# How to update a running system using protobuf from int32 to 64?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, producer-consumer

We have a running/production system, where an `int32` protobuf field is being communicated to and fro between components. We need to update it to `int64` on the fly without getting the current system down. And deployment would also take a lot of time so one component can get updated to `int64` while the other is still at `int32`. 
We need to update without any failures.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 10):

`int32` and `int64` are both communicated as "varint" (wire-type zero) - they are already wire compatible. So: *as long as* neither client nor server is currently sending 64-bit values, you can update each end independently - just change the `.proto` to use `int64` instead of `int32` and re-generate the generated code, and get it deployed. The data is wire compatible and will not change the seriaization format.

Note: you should not actually *use* values in the 64-bit range until **both ends** have been updated.

If you were changing from `fixed32`/`sfixed32` to `fixed64`/`sfixed64`, then this would represent a much bigger change and would require careful thought, usually involving introducing a **new** field (with a new number) for the 64-bit value, and migrating to it - probably putting the 32-bit value into *both* fields until both ends are deployed, then removing the old field and using just the 64-bit field.